# Regex for removing categories from (multilingual) URLs?

Tags: regex, parsing

I tried searching the archives, but nothing applies.

I need to Search&Replace the URLs of internal links throughout a website.

The original format used the

[domain]/[parent category]/[subcategory]/[possible further subcategory…]/[post title] structure,

while the new structure is [domain]/[post title]

To complicate things up, this is a multilingual website, so the URL structure can be either [domain]... or [domain]/it/... .

My regex skills are really bad. Can anybody suggest the correct expression to identify the [parent category]/[subcategory]/[possible further subcategory…]/  part?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A sequence without `/` can be written as `[^/]+`, and the `/` have to be escaped to `\/`. Take this expression:

`^([^/]+\/?[^/]{2}?\/)(.*?)([^/]+)$`

Would match:

- `^` : sequence start
- `[^/]+` : sequence with no slash
- `\/?` : optional slash
- `[^/]{2}?` : optional 2 char string (language)
- `.*?` : anything (will be left out) - lazy capture
- `[^/]+` : string with no `/` - greedy capture
- `$` : sequence end

Example:

```js
function convert(oldurl) {
  var m = oldurl.match(/^([^/]+\/?[^/]{2}?\/)(.*?)([^/]+)$/);
  if (m && m[3]) console.log(`${oldurl} -> ${m[1]}${m[3]}, removed: ${m[2]}`);
}

convert("domain.com/it/cat/sub/title1");
convert("domain.com/cat/sub/title2");
convert("domain.com/it/cat/title3");
convert("domain.com/title4");
```